# SQL: 3 Table Inner Join Returns Multiple Results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT video.name, video.description, video_source.url, bitcast_user.username
FROM video
INNER JOIN bitcast_user ON video.account_id = bitcast_user.id
INNER JOIN video_source ON video_source.video_id = {$_GET['id']};
```

This returns results with incorrect video names, descriptions and associated accounts but correct sources. There is a one-to-many relationship between users and videos, and videos and sources.

Comment: You need a proper `join` condition and then move the condition in the `on` to a `where` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't do an INNER JOIN on a variable - that belongs in the WHERE clause. (Actually - I was even surprised that this worked at all.) I think you need a query like this:

```
SELECT video.name, video.description, video_source.url, bitcast_user.username
  FROM video
  INNER JOIN bitcast_user ON video.account_id = bitcast_user.id
  INNER JOIN video_source ON video_source.video_id = video.video_id
  WHERE video_source.video_id = {$_GET['id']};
```

(I'm not sure about `video_source.video_id = video.video_id` because I don't know how the column is named in the `video` table.)